# How to add items to ComboBox at runtime using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

My goal is to have a user click on a `ComboBox`, type text in `ComboBox` and then hit enter and add that text as an item on the list.

My main problem is I don't know what event to use. I've looked through all of them and I didn't find any that I think would work for this kind of situation.

If there is an easier way to do this other than a `ComboBox` please mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to [`KeyUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821477.aspx) event and when user key-in `Enter` Add text to `Combobox`

```
comboBox1.KeyUp +=(comboBox1_KeyUp; // subscribe to an event.

private void comboBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text); // Add
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. interesting. Down voters please explain what is wrong?

Comment: Down voters, at least now you could remove your down vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add items in a `ComboBox` then try adding in this way `ComboBox1.Items.Add(your_object);`

*example:*

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
```

you can perform the above action using a `Button_Click` Event.

Not quite sure if you want to retrieve the added items from the Database. If so, then you can use `Databinding` to bind the ComboBox to a data source.

**OR**

Assuming you are loading the ComboBox with data from Database, you can also do this:

- Add a new row to your `DataSet`

  `ds.tables[0].rows.add(TextBox1.Text);`
- Update your `DataSet`

  `dataAdapter.update(ds);`
- Reload your `ComboBox` and you'll be able to see the items you inputted.

  `ComboBox1.datasource = ds;`

So,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string cs = "Data Source=ServerName; Initial Catalog=DatabaseName; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    string sql = "Your query goes here, i.e the info that you want to display in your ComboBox";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql,con);
    try
    {
        con.Open();                 
        Dataset ds = new DataSet();
        ds.tables[0].rows.add(TextBox1.Text);
        dataAdapter.update(ds);
        ComboBox1.datasource = ds;
    } 
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void comboBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //if Enter (return) key is pressed
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        //don't add text if it's empty
        if (comboBox1.Text != "")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                //exit event if text already exists
                if (comboBox1.Text == comboBox1.Items[i].ToString())
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            //add item to comboBox1
            comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some comment as to why you propose this piece of code.

Comment: don't add text to ComboBox if text is empty or if it already exists in the items